# stacking plots with R

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying to stack three plots over each other to study the diversity of each plot from one another. Being a newbie to R I still haven't managed to find a solution. I've tried the ggplot and multiplot but failed to accomplish the task. Maybe the header in my text file is the problem or I'm not even seeing the problem clearly! It'd be of great help if anyone can advise me in this regard..

My script is as follow:

```
defects <- read.table(file="C:/_____.txt",header=TRUE)
squareX <- c()        
squareY <- c()        

distance <- c(0, 17.0, 17.5, 34.5, 35.0, 52.0, 52.5, 69.5, 70.0, 87.0,
              87.5, 104.5, 105.0, 122.0, 122.5, 139.5)
square_beginning <- distance[seq(1,length(distance),2)] 

for ( i in 1:length(defects$x)){ 

  for (e in square_beginning){
    if (defects$x[i]>e & defects$x[i]<e+17.5) {
      squareX[i] <- e/17.5+1 
    }
    if (defects$y[i]>e & defects$y[i]<e+17.5) {
      squareY[i] <- e/17.5+1
    }
  }
}

defects<- cbind(defects,squareX,squareY)
#plot (defects)

cont <- read.table(file="C:/____.txt",header=TRUE)
squareX <- c()         
squareY <- c()         

distance <- c(0, 17.0, 17.5, 34.5, 35.0, 52.0, 52.5, 69.5, 70.0, 87.0,
              87.5, 104.5, 105.0, 122.0, 122.5, 139.5)
square_beginning <- distance[seq(1,length(distance),2)] 

for ( i in 1:length(cont$x)){ 

  for (e in square_beginning){  
    if (cont$x[i]>e & cont$x[i]<e+17.5) {
      squareX[i] <- e/17.5+1 
    }
    if (cont$y[i]>e & cont$y[i]<e+17.5) {
      squareY[i] <- e/17.5+1
    }
  }
}
par(mo=c(1,2))
plot(defects, main="test 1")
plot(cont, main="test 2")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's good that you provided your script but unfortunately it's not reproducible (e.g. "defects" is missing). See [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some info. If you make it reproducible, you are more likely to get good and quick answers to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack plots setting the `mfrow` or `mfcol` parameters of `par()`. For 3 rows and 1 column:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1)) #mfrow will fill by rows
```

or

```
par(mfcol=c(3,1)) #mfcol will fill by columns
```

Do this before your `plot()` statement. No need to use `ggplot2` or any other library.

**Update:**

Apparently I misunderstood your question, and if you want to add three datasets in one plot, you shouldn't need to use `par`, and do as @Carl Witthoft suggested and use `plot()` followed by `lines()` or `points()`.

Plotting this way will create a plot with axis limits based on the data passed to `plot()`. You can change that setting the limits manually with `xlim` and `ylim`:

```
plot(1:10, (1:10)^2, xlim=c(0, 15), ylim=c(0, 150))
lines(1:15, seq(1, 150, length=15))
points(0:10, seq(1, 150, length=11))
```

Comment: thanks @Molx ! that was precise and easy :) although the plot does not contain all the coordinates of interest. It kind of looks restricted .. So i used xaxt="n" in the plot line followed by axis(1, 139.5, by = 17, las=1).. but seems to be not working.. could you advise on how to solve this also.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear whether you want multiple plots on one page, as Molx' solution provides, or whether you want to overlay the data in a single plot.

If the latter, you have a few choices.  Try plotting one dataset, then `par(new=TRUE)`, then the next `plot` command will write onto the same graph. Beware of duplicated axes and scaling problems.

Or you might plot the first set, and then explicitly call `lines(cont[,1],cont[,2],...)` to plot more datasets.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear.. I want to overlay the data in a single plot. And so I used par(mfrow=c(1,1)) and that seems to have worked! I've so far managed to get two different sets of coordinates in the same plot. As I mentioned before the problem is that the plot is not complete. Seems to be restricted. For instance, I wanted to plot till 140,140 but the displayed plot is until 120,120 even with coordinates beyond that..

Comment: @Ram.V  Good solution -- now, `plot` by default sets the  ranges to the min/max of the  first dataset plotted.  If you know the range you want, set it explicitly with `plot(x,y, xlim=c(min,max), ylim=c(min,max)`